# C++ creating a Templatized function to sort both int and strings

Tags: c++, string, sorting, templates

I'm working with Template Functions and am looking to create one that sorts both ints and strings. I have managed to get it working with ints but having trouble with strings.

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
void print(T arr[], int n);
template <class T>
void swap(T arr[], int i, int j);
template <class T>
T getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end);
template <class T>
void selectionSort(T arr[], int n);



int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int iarr[] = { 3,5,9,2,1,7,8,4,0,6 };
    selectionSort<int>(iarr, n);
    print<int>(iarr, n);

    cout << endl;
    string sarr[] = { "skunk", "hedgehog", "aardvark", "zebra", "rat", "cat", "hippopotamus", "hamster", "manatee", "red panda" };
    selectionSort<string>(sarr, n);
    print<string>(sarr, n);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}




// PRE: length of arr = n
// PARAM: arr = array of integers of length n
// POST: prints arr[0:n]
template <class T>
void print(T arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}


// PRE: i, j < length of arr
// PARAM: arr = array of integers of length n, i and j are indexes
// POST: swaps arr[i] with arr[j]
template <class T>
void swap(T arr[], int i, int j) {
    T temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}


// PRE: 0 <= start < end <= length of arr
// PARAM: arr = array of integers
//        start = start index of sub-array
//        end = end index of sub-array + 1
// POST: returns index of smallest value in arr{start:end}
template <class T>
T getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    T smallest = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}


// PRE: length of arr = n
// PARAM: arr = array of integers of length n
// POST: sorts arr in ascending order
template <class T>
void selectionSort(T arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        int smallest = getSmallest(arr, i, n);
        swap(arr, i, smallest);
    }
}
```

I know I need to find some way to make "smallest" somehow able to work for strings. But simply turning it from int to template T isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the meaning of "isn't working" ? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number I get the some of the following errors from the compiler "

main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void selectionSort(T*, int) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
main.cpp:27:31:   required from here
main.cpp:82:7: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
   int smallest = getSmallest(arr, i, n);
       ^~~~~~~~"

Comment: Please edit the question to include the compiler output, then delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it.

The only thing off is that `getSmallest()` returns an index regardless of what `T` is. So that part should not be templated.

```
template <class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    int smallest = start;
```

Comment: I tried that, now I'm getting compiler issues regarded to overloading?

main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void selectionSort(T*, int) [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:22:28:   required from here
main.cpp:82:29: error: call of overloaded ‘getSmallest(int*&, int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
   int smallest = getSmallest(arr, i, n);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
template <class T>
T getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    T smallest = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

has an invalid return type. For an array of objects of the type std::string it will have the return type std::string.

It should look like

```
template <class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    int smallest = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Do not forget to change also the function template declaration

```
template <class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end)
```

Comment: I tried that, now I'm getting compiler issues regarded to overloading?

main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void selectionSort(T*, int) [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:22:28:   required from here
main.cpp:82:29: error: call of overloaded ‘getSmallest(int*&, int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
   int smallest = getSmallest(arr, i, n);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You changed to many `int` to `T`.

> ```
> template <class T>
> T getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
>     T smallest = start;
>     for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
>         if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
>             smallest = i;
>         }
>     }
>     return smallest;
> }
> ```

If you use `int` for the index then `smallest` should be `int` and the return type should be `int`, not `T`. Actually I suggest to use `size_t` for indices (unless you want to pass iterators):

```
template <class T>
size_t getSmallest(T arr[], size_t start, size_t end) {
    size_t smallest = start;
    for (size_t i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```